# Copy a column from one dataframe to another when they both share an index in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to copy a column of data from one dataframe to another, using the index as a reference. When copying the column, I want to fill any entry that does not appear in both dataframes with a NaN.

For example, I have these two dummy dfs:

```
df1 = 
       col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4
index
A          1      4      7     10
B          2      5      8     11
C          3      6      9     12
```

```
df2 = 
       col_5  col_6
index
A         13     15
C         14     16
```

And I would like to copy col_5 to `df1` based on the shared index so `df1` looks like:

```
df1 = 
       col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4  col_5
index
A          1      4      7     10   15
B          2      5      8     11   NaN
C          3      6      9     12   16
```

Since they're different lengths I can't simply do `df1['col_5'] = df2['col_5']`, and I didn't have any success with a  `df1.merge(df2, how='left')`, and then I'd have to drop any unwanted columns anyway.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why the column_5 disappears ?

Comment: `merge` is the right way to go for this sort of thing. When you say you "didn't have any success" with it, what did you try, and what was wrong with your result?

Comment: You are sure `df1['col_5'] = df2['col_5']` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

The merge function will work when using index as join key AND selecting out the columns from the right dataframe. 
`merge` has parameters to use left and right index in join. Example below works:

```
merged_df = df_1.merge(df_2['col_5'], left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `df1.insert(df1.shape[1], "col_5", df2["col_5"]`, which will put `col_5` at the end (`df1.shape[1]` returns the number of columns in df1) of `df1` with the indices properly matched.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2.col_5], axis='columns')
```

That said, as another commenter mentioned, `df1['col_5'] = df2['col_5']` should work too.